# How to implement custom navigationBar Fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, kotlin, navigationbar

I'm trying to implement custom navigationbar fragment in my project but i'm not able set title and left button. In this fragment i'm using textview to set icon and title. I know i can use custom toolbar but i don't want to use custom toolbar so using navigation bar fragment and i can use this navigation fragment as toolbar wherever i need and set left button, right button and all
below is my NavigationBarFragment:-

```
    class NavigationBarFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var leftButton: TextView
    lateinit var titleTextView: TextView
    private var buttonChangeListener: ButtonImageChangeListener? = null

    interface ButtonImageChangeListener {

        fun changeMenuButtonImage()
    }



    fun newInstance(title: String, isLeft: Boolean): NavigationBarFragment {

        val navigationBarFragment = NavigationBarFragment()

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("title", title)
        bundle.putBoolean("isLeft", isLeft)

        navigationBarFragment.arguments = bundle
        return navigationBarFragment
    }



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_bar, container, false)

        leftButton = view!!.findViewById(R.id.leftButton)
        titleTextView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.title)
        titleTextView.setText(arguments!!.getString("title"))

        if (arguments!!.getBoolean("isLeft")) {

            leftButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            leftButton.setOnClickListener(this)
        } else {
            leftButton.visibility = View.GONE
        }


    }

    interface navigationButtonListener {

        fun leftButtonPressed()
    }


    private var listener: navigationButtonListener? = null

    fun getListener(): navigationButtonListener? {
        return listener
    }

    fun setListener(listener: navigationButtonListener) {
        this.listener = listener
    }

    fun getButtonChangeListener(): ButtonImageChangeListener? {
        return buttonChangeListener
    }

    fun setButtonChangeListener(buttonChangeListener: ButtonImageChangeListener) {
        this.buttonChangeListener = buttonChangeListener
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        if (v != null) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.title) run {

            } else if (v!!.getId() == R.id.leftButton) {
                if (this.listener != null) {
                    this.listener!!.leftButtonPressed()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

below is method which i'm implementing in Activity:

```
private var navigationBar: NavigationBarFragment? = null
    private fun loadNavigationbar() {
    navigationBar = NavigationBarFragment().newInstance("Report",true)



    navigationBar?.setListener(this)
    navigationBar?.setButtonChangeListener(object : NavigationBarFragment.ButtonImageChangeListener {
        override fun changeMenuButtonImage() {

            //title
            navigationBar!!.titleTextView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            //navigationBar!!.titleTextView.setTypeface(Application.HelveticaNeue_Medium)
            var aa= navigationBar!!.titleTextView.text
            navigationBar!!.titleTextView.setText("Report Activity")

            //Menu Button
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setText(resources.getResourceName(R.drawable.ic_navigate_back))
            // navigationBar.leftButton.setTypeface(Application.FONT_AWESOME)
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setTextSize(24F)
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5)

            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)


            navigationBar!!.navigationBarBaseLayout.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

            val ssbProfile = SpannableStringBuilder(" ")
            ssbProfile.setSpan(ImageSpan(this@ReportActivity, R.drawable.ic_navigate_back), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setText(ssbProfile, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setTextSize(32F)
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
            navigationBar!!.leftButton.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5)

        }
    })
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.navigationBar, this!!.navigationBar!!)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()

}
```

Below is My xml code:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigationBarBaseLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leftButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="C"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="48dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLength="30"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="CATELOGUE"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"  />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rightFirstButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightSecondButton"
    android:text="c"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rightSecondButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightThirdButton"
    android:text="c"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rightThirdButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="c"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you like to type so many `!!`s? I mean, you could retrieve the variable to a `val` first, then set it to the field, and then you wouldn't need any of these `!!`s.

Comment: yes there is a reason for that

Comment: It was a trick question, as not really, you're just not using smartcasting.

Comment: Can you make this work in kotlin? as i'm beginner in kotlin and not getting what's wrong i'm doing.

Comment: If you assign a nullable variable to a `val`, then after the first null-check (either use of `!!` or `if(x != null) {`), it'll be smart-cast to non-null type. So you won't need the `!!`s below it anymore. But a common practice is to use `?: return` instead of `!!`, assuming that is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some How i solve this but in java not in kotlin. This is for left button for right apply same as left button.If any one find solution in kotlin let me know i will accept his answer.

below is my NavigationBar  code:

```
    public class NewNavigationBarFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView leftButton;
    public TextView titleTextView;
    public RelativeLayout navigationBarBaseLayout;
    private ButtonImageChangeListener buttonChangeListener;


    public interface ButtonImageChangeListener {

        void changeMenuButtonImage();
    }

    public interface navigationButtonListener {

        void leftButtonPressed();


    }

    private navigationButtonListener listener;

    public navigationButtonListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public void setListener(navigationButtonListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public ButtonImageChangeListener getButtonChangeListener() {
        return buttonChangeListener;
    }

    public void setButtonChangeListener(ButtonImageChangeListener buttonChangeListener) {
        this.buttonChangeListener = buttonChangeListener;
    }

    public NewNavigationBarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static NewNavigationBarFragment newInstance(String title, boolean isLeft) {
        NewNavigationBarFragment navigationBarFragment = new NewNavigationBarFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("title", title);
        bundle.putBoolean("isLeft", isLeft);


        navigationBarFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return navigationBarFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_bar, container, false);

        leftButton = view.findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
        titleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        navigationBarBaseLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.navigationBarBaseLayout);


        if (getArguments().getBoolean("isLeft")) {
            leftButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            leftButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            leftButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (buttonChangeListener != null) {
            buttonChangeListener.changeMenuButtonImage();
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.title) {

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.leftButton) {
            if (this.listener != null) {
                this.listener.leftButtonPressed();
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Call below code in activity and don't forget to `implement` navigationbar `listener` and declare `navigationBar` globally

private fun loadNavigationbar() {
    navigationBar = NewNavigationBarFragment.newInstance("", true)

```
navigationBar!!.setListener(this)
navigationBar!!.setButtonChangeListener(object : NewNavigationBarFragment.ButtonImageChangeListener {
    override fun changeMenuButtonImage() {
        //title
        navigationBar!!.titleTextView.setText("Reports")
        // navigationBar!!.titleTextView.setTypeface(Application.HelveticaNeue_Medium)
        navigationBar!!.navigationBarBaseLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        navigationBar!!.titleTextView.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))

        val ssbProfile = SpannableStringBuilder(" ")
        ssbProfile.setSpan(ImageSpan(this@ReportActivity, R.drawable.ic_navigate_back), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
        navigationBar!!.leftButton.setText(ssbProfile, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
        navigationBar!!.leftButton.setTextSize(32F)
        navigationBar!!.leftButton.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
        navigationBar!!.leftButton.setPadding(15, 5, 15, 5)
        navigationBar!!.leftButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
})

val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.navigationBar, navigationBar!!)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

}